# Does one need a new toothbrush for Pesach or can he scrub his current toothbrush in Listerine?

Tags: passover, medicine, chametz-leaven, kashering-kosherization, teeth

Must one necessarily use a new toothbrush for Pesach on can he soak the toothbrush and scrub it in Listerine?

AFAIK, Listerine is KP, based on what I saw fairly recently, on I think, Star-K site. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Listerine) states its composition is:

> The active ingredients listed on Listerine bottles are essential oils
>   which are menthol 0.042%, thymol 0.064%, methyl salicylate 0.06%, and
>   eucalyptol 0.092%.[14] In combination all have an antiseptic effect
>   and there is some thought that methyl salicylate may have an anti
>   inflammatory effect as well.[15] Ethanol, which is toxic to bacteria
>   at concentrations of 40%, is present in concentrations of 21.6% in the
>   flavored product and 26.9% in the original gold Listerine
>   Antiseptic.[16] At this concentration, the ethanol serves to dissolve
>   the active ingredients.

I used Listerine as an example, but, if one scrubbed the toothbrush extremely well so that there was no visible food and, just to be sure, soaked it in Listerine or some similar antiseptic that would make any left-over food in the bristles invisible, it sounds to me that this would be fine. Or is there some other concern with toothbrushes beyond this?

Comment: Since a toothbrush is only used with cold water, why would one need a new one at all? Why not simply clean it off from visible food leftovers?

Comment: @DannySchoemann I'm uncertain what the "cold water" aspect is about. Also, AFAIK, chametz has a bigger problem than mere visibility. I have porcelain serving plates that I use only for cold items (e.g. cake plates). Yet, I don't believe that I can use them for Pesach.

Comment: Cold Water: See Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 451:22 סימן תנא - דיני הגעלת כלים - http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_29.html#HtmpReportNum0022_L2 -  where he states: כָּל הַכֵּלִים, אֲפִלּוּ שֶׁל חֶרֶס, שֶׁנִּשְׁתַּמֵּשׁ בָּהֶם חָמֵץ בְּצוֹנֵן, מֻתָּר לְהִשְׁתַּמֵּשׁ בָּהֶם מַצָּה אֲפִלּוּ בְּחַמִּין - with certain caveats. Maybe you can use your cake plates. :-)

Comment: BTW: You cannot Kasher with Listerine - only with clean water. So either you need new ones, or you simply need to use water to wash them.

Comment: @DannySchoemann - Thanks! The 2nd is an eye-opener! I have to read this a bit further! Maybe, I really CAN use those nice cake plates, after all!

Comment: The issue might be the chametz between your teeth when you scrub that gets stuck between the bristles. So your last brush before Pesach should be with your chametz brush then floss.

Comment: @CashCow - If I understand you, you're saying that someone eats chametz close to the prohibition deadline, but doesn't brush his teeth until after the deadline. When he does, now there is chametz in the toothbrush. This raises a separate problem, possibly, in that he has chametz around, no?

Comment: If you eat chametz close to the deadline, there is an extra hour when you are allowed to own chametz but not eat it. (You destroy your chametz during this time).During that time you should clean your teeth and floss and at least get rid of chametz on the toothbrush the best you can.

Comment: Absorption for toothbrush bristles does seem to be a machlokes (though the gemara clearly states "ayn sechitah bese'ar," and nylon is far less absorbent). According to the tzad that there isn't sechitah, there would only be a chashash that there was chametz stuck between the bristles. If you clean thoroughly, then either 1) the chametz comes out, problem solved or 2) the chametz is "stuck" anyhow, and will receive bittul when you do biur, so there's no danger of accidentally ingesting it. Not a problem.

Comment: @CashCow - can you quote a source for your contention that you have to brush your teeth before the deadline for Issur Chametz?

Comment: you have to remove it. Brushing teeth is the means, not the ends

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky - Your comment seems to be close to a viable answer if you can source and tie things up a bit. Perhaps, with luck, I can get an answer to this question before the question, itself becomes chametz ;-)